# how to find who is department head of employee USING IN CLAUSE in php

Tags: php

```
$department_id=19
$deptshead(17,19,3)
$sql_depthead ="SELECT * FROM nonaudit_employee WHERE status = 'Active' AND rights = 3 AND deptshead IN(".$department.")AND cand_id!= ".$cand_id;
```

its working fine but

it only match first dept head cant check the second dept value???

Comment: Hint: the SQL *string* you are trying to create needs to be `"...AND deptshead IN(17,19,3) AND..."`, so think about how you would use `$deptshead` to create such a string...

Comment: bro $depthead ids db field value .iam just show you.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 17,19,3
    [3] => 21,22
    [4] => 13
    [5] => 14
    [6] => 5
    [7] => 25
)

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 17,19,3
    [3] => 21,22
    [4] => 13
    [5] => 14
    [6] => 5
    [7] => 25
) how to conver [3] and [2] vale also convert array a single array value

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I correct understood.
You can try to use:

```
$inClause = implode(",", $deptshead);
```

And after that use `$inClause` var in your query